# WP: custom search

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I really can't figure this out and it drives me crazy. I added my own custom search function in functions.php to be able to search in post meta.

```
function custom_search_query( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_search ) {
      echo 'Is search: true <br>';
        $query->set('meta_query', array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'wpcf-description',
                'value'     => $query->query_vars['s'],
                'compare'   => 'LIKE'
            )
        ));

      var_dump($query->get('meta_query'));
    }
  }
  add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_search_query',9999);
```

The var_dump gives me this result:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(16) "wpcf-description" ["value"]=> string(18) "Korte beschrijving" ["compare"]=> string(4) "LIKE" } }
```

so I assume that the meta_query is correct. This is the full query:

```
object(WP_Query)#754 (46) { ["query"]=> array(1) { ["s"]=> string(12) "beschrijving" } ["query_vars"]=> array(53) { ["s"]=> string(12) "beschrijving" ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["m"]=> string(0) "" ["p"]=> int(0) ["post_parent"]=> string(0) "" ["subpost"]=> string(0) "" ["subpost_id"]=> string(0) "" ["attachment"]=> string(0) "" ["attachment_id"]=> int(0) ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["static"]=> string(0) "" ["pagename"]=> string(0) "" ["page_id"]=> int(0) ["second"]=> string(0) "" ["minute"]=> string(0) "" ["hour"]=> string(0) "" ["day"]=> int(0) ["monthnum"]=> int(0) ["year"]=> int(0) ["w"]=> int(0) ["category_name"]=> string(0) "" ["tag"]=> string(0) "" ["cat"]=> string(0) "" ["tag_id"]=> string(0) "" ["author"]=> string(0) "" ["author_name"]=> string(0) "" ["feed"]=> string(0) "" ["tb"]=> string(0) "" ["paged"]=> int(0) ["meta_key"]=> string(0) "" ["meta_value"]=> string(0) "" ["preview"]=> string(0) "" ["sentence"]=> string(0) "" ["title"]=> string(0) "" ["fields"]=> string(0) "" ["menu_order"]=> string(0) "" ["embed"]=> string(0) "" ["category__in"]=> array(0) { } ["category__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["category__and"]=> array(0) { } ["post__in"]=> array(0) { } ["post__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["post_name__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__and"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_slug__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_slug__and"]=> array(0) { } ["post_parent__in"]=> array(0) { } ["post_parent__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["author__in"]=> array(0) { } ["author__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["meta_query"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(16) "wpcf-description" ["value"]=> string(12) "beschrijving" ["compare"]=> string(4) "LIKE" } } } ["tax_query"]=> object(WP_Tax_Query)#3628 (6) { ["queries"]=> array(0) { } ["relation"]=> string(3) "AND" ["table_aliases":protected]=> array(0) { } ["queried_terms"]=> array(0) { } ["primary_table"]=> NULL ["primary_id_column"]=> NULL } ["meta_query"]=> bool(false) ["date_query"]=> bool(false) ["post_count"]=> int(0) ["current_post"]=> int(-1) ["in_the_loop"]=> bool(false) ["comment_count"]=> int(0) ["current_comment"]=> int(-1) ["found_posts"]=> int(0) ["max_num_pages"]=> int(0) ["max_num_comment_pages"]=> int(0) ["is_single"]=> bool(false) ["is_preview"]=> bool(false) ["is_page"]=> bool(false) ["is_archive"]=> bool(false) ["is_date"]=> bool(false) ["is_year"]=> bool(false) ["is_month"]=> bool(false) ["is_day"]=> bool(false) ["is_time"]=> bool(false) ["is_author"]=> bool(false) ["is_category"]=> bool(false) ["is_tag"]=> bool(false) ["is_tax"]=> bool(false) ["is_search"]=> bool(true) ["is_feed"]=> bool(false) ["is_comment_feed"]=> bool(false) ["is_trackback"]=> bool(false) ["is_home"]=> bool(false) ["is_404"]=> bool(false) ["is_embed"]=> bool(false) ["is_paged"]=> bool(false) ["is_admin"]=> bool(false) ["is_attachment"]=> bool(false) ["is_singular"]=> bool(false) ["is_robots"]=> bool(false) ["is_posts_page"]=> bool(false) ["is_post_type_archive"]=> bool(false) ["query_vars_hash":"WP_Query":private]=> string(32) "bf0637eea0229d81220060e8015682ce" ["query_vars_changed":"WP_Query":private]=> bool(false) ["thumbnails_cached"]=> bool(false) ["stopwords":"WP_Query":private]=> NULL ["compat_fields":"WP_Query":private]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(15) "query_vars_hash" [1]=> string(18) "query_vars_changed" } ["compat_methods":"WP_Query":private]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(16) "init_query_flags" [1]=> string(15) "parse_tax_query" } }
```

I don't get any results while I have at least one post that contains the value I'm looking for. What's wrong with this code? Please help since I'm trying to make work for some time but not able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, you are attempting to query the meta values only on the posts that are initially returned from the search, which is none. I.E. your query looks for posts that have the search term in either the title/content ***and*** in your meta query.

Clear your search query after applying your custom meta query:

```
function custom_search_query( $query ) {

    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_search() ) {

        echo 'Is search: true <br>';

        $query->set('meta_query', array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'wpcf-description',
                'value'     => $query->get('s'),
                'compare'   => 'LIKE'
            )
        ));

        // Clear the initial search query
        $query->set('s', '');

    }

}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_search_query',9999);
```